# XMLParser in SwiftUI Decoder.shared

Tags: xml, swiftui, xml-parsing, decoding, decoder

I have a Decoder written using [SwiftyXMLParser](https://github.com/yahoojapan/SwiftyXMLParser)

And I am in a hurry for help, as my knowledge is not enough to use decoded data in SwiftUI. Namely, I want to use the resulting text in other files of the project. From the example I think you should understand what I want. But the program doesn't work. Point out a bug or help write a code to use it in SwiftUI

**XML**

```
<horo>
<date yesterday="02.05.2021" today="03.05.2021" tomorrow="04.05.2021" tomorrow02="05.05.2021"/>
<aries>
<yesterday> Сегодня вам, возможно, будет трудно собраться с мыслями и еще труднее решиться на какие-либо активные действия. Не стоит стараться пересилить упрямый организм, он таких вещей не прощает. </yesterday>
<today> Сегодня вы будете способны превратить самые тривиальные слова в изысканный сонет. Если вам удастся еще и слушателя найти соответствующего - проблема "где и с кем провести субботний вечер" будет решена. Возможно, навсегда. </today>
<tomorrow> Сегодня вам предстоит день, полный борьбы с непониманием в как рядах близких вам людей так и среди прочих. Возможно, вы его так и не победите. </tomorrow>
<tomorrow02> Сила вашего обаяния сегодня во многом будет зависеть от изысканности вашей речи. С помощью пары-другой изящный оборотов вы сможете покорить чье-то сердце. </tomorrow02>
</aries>
</horo>
```

**HoroscopeDecoder.swift**

```
import SwiftyXMLParser
```

I am very broken, my head is boiling. I can't sleep, I just don't know what to do. help me please

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to check out [ask]. In your question, you said it "doesn't work" but you haven't given any details as to *how*. Are there errors? A result you didn't expect? You also didn't include any example of the XML you're parsing or any of your types, making it difficult, if not impossible, to debug. If possible, include a [mre].

Comment: I made an attempt to explain what I was failing. It seems obvious to me, but no one understands me

Comment: So is your `completion` returning the information you expect but it's just not showing up in your SwiftUI view?

Comment: @jnpdx I'm sorry, but I want to warn you that I am very weak in Swift and do not always understand what I mean. The same can be said about my English :)

But I think you understand me.

Comment: If in `func updateText () {HoroscopeDecoder.shared.run (sign: .scorpio, period: .today) {prediction in self.text = prediction}` Add `print (prediction)` then in the Debag area I see the text that I want to display in my `var body: some View { Text ("") }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything else is working like you said it is in the comments, this should probably fix it:

```
class ViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var text = ""
    
    func updateText() {
        HoroscopeDecoder.shared.run(sign: .scorpio, period: .today) { prediction in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
              self.text = prediction
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(viewModel.text)
            .padding()
            .onAppear {
                viewModel.updateText()
            }
    }
    
}
```

In general, you don't want to do asynchronous tasks in your `View` code and especially not in `init`, which may be called *many* times. Instead, call it in `onAppear`.

Also, your URL task will return on a different thread -- you want to use `DispatchQueue.main.async` once you're ready to update the UI.

Comment: Very cool! It works, you are my hero!
While the topic is hot, I want to ask you more:

If in one file I want to call data for different `(sign: .(other sign), period: .(today, tomorrow))`

I need to create a new `func updateText ()` 

for each or is there an easier way?

Comment: Great. You can accept the answer be clicking the green checkmark. Regarding your followup, you can change `updateText` to take parameters that would be then passed through to `HoroscopeDecoder`

Comment: But I do not want to change the text, but add more

Comment: @PavelM. okay, then I guess I'm not clear on what you're asking.